# Django Rest Framework: XLSXRenderer -- How to check condition for queryset and return a Response

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-drf-renderer

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ReadOnlyModelViewSet
from drf_renderer_xlsx.mixins import XLSXFileMixin
from drf_renderer_xlsx.renderers import XLSXRenderer
from .models import MyExampleModel
from .serializers import MyExampleSerializer

class MyExampleViewSet(XLSXFileMixin, ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MyExampleSerializer
    renderer_classes = [XLSXRenderer]
    filename = 'my_export.xlsx'

    def get_queryset(self):
        start_date = self.request.query_params.get('start_date', None)
        end_date = self.request.query_params.get('end_date', None)
        queryset = MyExampleModel.objects..filter(created__range=[start_date, end_date])
        Return queryset

        # What I want to do
        # If not queryset:
        #    Return Response({"message": "Exporting Fail"})
        

# Is there a way to check if queryset is None and return a Error Message instead of an empty Excel
# I think that I not allow return Response in the get_queryset function
```

Currently, I am trying to build a function to export excel file. I just want to know is there a way to check if the queryset is None and then I can return a Response({"message": "Exporting Fail, Empty"})

If you know where can I research it would help me a lot.
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing the filtering in `filter_queryset` or `get_queryset` so what you already have is correct. But `get_queryset` has to return a `queryset`, not a `Response` object.

You will access the actual object in `get_object` method.

```
    def get_object(self):
        """
        Returns the object the view is displaying.

        You may want to override this if you need to provide non-standard
        queryset lookups.  Eg if objects are referenced using multiple
        keyword arguments in the url conf.
        """
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        # Perform the lookup filtering.
        lookup_url_kwarg = self.lookup_url_kwarg or self.lookup_field

        assert lookup_url_kwarg in self.kwargs, (
            'Expected view %s to be called with a URL keyword argument '
            'named "%s". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` '
            'attribute on the view correctly.' %
            (self.__class__.__name__, lookup_url_kwarg)
        )

        filter_kwargs = {self.lookup_field: self.kwargs[lookup_url_kwarg]}
        obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, **filter_kwargs)

        # May raise a permission denied
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)

        return obj
```

If you don't want to raise a 404 if queryset is empty, you will have to first adjust those few final lines.

Then, as you can only `retrieve` and `list` in your view set, adjust those methods accordingly.

```
    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        if not instance:
            return Response({"message": "Exporting Fail"})
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Or you don't alter `get_object` at all and handle 404

```
    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            instance = self.get_object()
            serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        except Http404:
            return Response({"message": "Exporting Fail"})
```

but imo it's not a clean solution.